# "ValidatioError: Value ... is not a valid choice" in Django even with a valid choice

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model with a `object_type` field where the choices should be numbers and the human readable a string like below:

```py
OBJECT_TYPES = (
    (0, "analog-input"),
    (1, "analog-output"),
    (2, "analog-value")
)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    object_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=OBJECT_TYPES,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

However, when I try to create an object and assign an integer value to object_type I get a `ValidationError` that the `object_type` is not a valid choice and I can't understand how to configure it properly. I have tried with `CharField`, `TextField` and `IntegerField`.

```py
obj = MyModel.objects.create(object_type=2)
obj.full_clean()

ValidationError: {'object_type': ["Value '2' is not a valid choice."]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a `CharField`, the keys should be *strings*, so `'0'`, not `0`:

```
OBJECT_TYPES = (
    ('0', "analog-input"),
    ('1', "analog-output"),
    ('2', "analog-value")
)
```

an alternative is to work with an `IntegerField`:

```
OBJECT_TYPES = (
    (0, "analog-input"),
    (1, "analog-output"),
    (2, "analog-value")
)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    object_type = models.IntegerField(
        choices=OBJECT_TYPES,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```